# Apple Watch Images not showing on simulator

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

I am working with the apple watch and I would like to just simply set an image in the storyboard. It is a png file and I set it in the storyboard, but it doesn't show up in the simulator. I have tried all of the aspect and fitting options. I believe the view is called a wkinterfaceimage. I have also tried adding programmatically and that does not show up either. Hidden is not checked. Any ideas of what I might be missing?

Comment: Have you added your image in Assets folder ? if so to which target does it belong to ?

Comment: I am using regular files, not the image assets

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have your image included as a file in your app's bundle select the file, choose *File Inspector* and add the target under *Target Membership*:

[image]

Comment: I added to the target but, still image not displaying