# My WatchKit app doesn't display its UI

Tags: cocoa-touch, swift, watchkit

I'm trying to give my app a watch kit extension - partly because I think it'd be kinda cool, and partly because I thought I'd have a bash at swift at the same time.  Trouble is, it doesn't work!

I've set up my UI Storyboard in Watchkit App (just a simple image and label to start with, just to prove it works), and I've written some Swift code in WatchKit extension - this:

InterfaceController.swift

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
//import JourneyKit

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {
    @IBOutlet weak var favouriteJourneyTable: WKInterfaceTable!

    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)

        // Configure interface objects here.
        WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(["request": "refreshFavourites"],
            reply: { (replyInfo, error) -> Void in
                // TODO: process reply data
                NSLog("Reply: \(replyInfo)")
        })    
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
        super.didDeactivate()
    }
}
```

I've hooked up favouriteJourneyTable to a table in my WatchUI.

To complicate matters, I do have a Notification scene - because my app needs that.  I have been careful to ensure that what I'm running is my Watchkit App and not my notification.  Nevertheless, when I run my app the UI doesn't show.  I just get a black screen with the time in the corner.

I know that this code is getting called because, in the console, I get the following:

```
2015-04-05 18:30:22.599 Testapp WatchKit Extension[1151:197034] Reply: nil
```

Which, in it's own way, is frustrating - because AppDelegate contains code to respond (not to mention a breakpoint) and it's clearly not getting called.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply{

    // Performs task on phone here

    // Sending back a reply
    if ([[userInfo valueForKey:@"request"] length]>0) {
        //NSMutableDictionary *reply = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [reply setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello from %@", [userInfo valueForKey:@"SiteName"]] forKey:@"Message"];
    }
}
```

The UI issue is the most concerning at the moment, followed by the AppDelegate issue.  I need to find some way of getting my array out of my iOS preferences and onto the screen on my WatchApp. Any ideas?

Commenting out WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication... (just to try to get the UI to show (clutching at straws) makes no difference.

Comment: Well, if setting a breakpoint doesn´t work, do some log outputs then! Is the userInfo Dictionary there? Does the key 'request' exist? Etc...

Comment: The bigger question is why the UI doesn't display at all - the rest comes later.

Comment: Well, can you show a screenshot of the Storyboard? Or upload the project somewhere and share it here?

Answer (score 0):

You know when the one thing you need when programming is a brown paper bag?  This is it. I shamefacedly offer the following solution (having fiddled around with stand alone test harnesses, and grepped Stack Overflow).  It's simple, it's obvious, and I'm embarrassed :-(

When building a UI out of images, one really does need to include those images when generating the target.  D'oh.  Anyway, you can read more here: [Apple Watch Images not showing on simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27299572/apple-watch-images-not-showing-on-simulator)

My apologies for wasting everyones time!