# Apple Watch Simulator Not Showing Images

Tags: image, watchkit, xcode-6.2

I'm trying to show images but the simulator won't load any images at all. It just shows a blank space where they're supposed to be. Yes, the targets are all correct and have been put also for watch targets. I've restarted this several times and no images work at all.

I have already selected the copies and targets when moving files into the project.

I have already checked my build phases/settings and the images folder is there.

I have tried resetting the program, resetting the iOS simulator, reset my computer, installed ALL updates, and everything is up to date but still no images are showing. What am I missing?

At this point, there is no code, just the user interface.

[image: Images Not Showing]

I did read that someone somewhere mentioned that make sure the selected image has the targets selected... except targets do NOT show up on images.

[image: No Image Target]

Comment: i have same issue but i set image from code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added a full directory. I'm not sure but I think there is a bug with new version of XCode. Do that:

1. Create a group in XCode
2. Add to this group all images you want to use
3. Add all images to your "Gold Hits WatchKit App" target

This should be fix your problem ;)

Comment: I'll try it when I get home

Comment: Your solution was right! I don't see why reference doesn't work though if it's an option the program gives you.

Answer (score 1):

The *Target Membership* area in InterfaceBuilder is not available for contents in folder *references*.

Folders added as reference are displayed in blue in Xcode.

Make sure the *Create folder references* is NOT checked when adding the folder to the project.

[image]

Then see this answer: [Apple Watch Images not showing on simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27299572/apple-watch-images-not-showing-on-simulator/27301190#27301190)

Comment: What do you mean by physically adding them? I have copied the files into the folders already and even dragged them, too. The physical files are in the location of the app files.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You have added the folder as a *reference* to the Xcode project.

Comment: it works now, but why doesn't it allow images to be displayed if its a reference folder????