# Image is not visible on Watch App programatically

Tags: objective-c, watchkit

I have a very weird issue. I have a watch app and I am trying to display an image programatically. When I debug the code, I can see the image is correctly loaded but on simulator or real device I cannot see the image. I have added that image in both watch and extension bundle resources.

Firstly I use the code below to open the view.

```
 NSArray *objects =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"MainPageView",@"InterfaceController",@"PoseImageView",nil];            
[self presentControllerWithNames:objects contexts:nil];
```

Inside `PoseImageView` I am trying to display an image with:

```
UIImage *imgTest = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1.jpg", strAngle]];  // I can see 1.jpg in debugger
[_imgPose setImage: imgTest];
```

The image is not there on watch or simulator. I am wondering how to fix the issue.

Note: From assets its not loading as well.

Note2: I can only display the image if the view is initial view.

Comment: UIImage *imgTest = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1.jpg", strAngle]];  // I can see 1.jpg in debugger
Syntax seems incorrect ?
Use it
UIImage *imgTest = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1.jpg"]];  // I can see 1.jpg in debugger

Comment: It's not about the definition of UIImage. I tried what you wrote as well.

Comment: check your image its valid .jpg by checking its get info and name is correct and added in target / build files http://i.stack.imgur.com/v3Z0A.jpg

Comment: I tried many images in assets catalog or bundle resources. I just cannot display it unless the view is not initial view.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27299572/apple-watch-images-not-showing-on-simulator

Comment: Yes, already visited that post and couldn't fix with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174170/discussion-between-iphonemaclover-and-birdcage).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use imageNamed for .jpg which will not work.
Try using

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"imageName"] ofType:@"jpg"];
  UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Comment: Didn't help. I can already see image in debugger but can't show it on display.

Comment: Did u add the image in watchkit extension’s asset catalog?

Comment: Yes I added it.